# Should I use the Google Maps API or the Google Maps iframe embed feature for a static site?

Tags: web-development, google-maps

Is it common to use [Google maps embedded `<iframe>`](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for a static site? Or is it best practice to use the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) when deploying the website?

Comment: Do you have data you want to layer on top of the map?  Like adding extra pins?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller not extra pins, just some contact information. Thanks for updating it. I guess I left it quite open to interpretation. I guess I’m just trying to find what is the common practise, if people would even go to in depth with it for just a basic static website.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to customize the map, you can use an iframe. Though Google will rank your page content higher if the map is loaded on the page and not through an iframe. Googlebot and crawler doesn't count iframe content in the same way that it counts content loaded onto a page.

So if you're trying to rank your site you'll get a slight boost from not using an iframe. And by using the API you can customize the map and add extra features. If you just want a simple solution so that you can spend your time working on other coding projects then you can use an iframe and achieve similar results.

Answer (score 2):

Makes no difference. But in terms of performance it is better to implement a static image. The easiest was to do so, is to use something like this [Google Static Map Maker](https://staticmapmaker.com/google/).